# Unable to get response in css selector or xpath expression

Tags: css, python-2.7, selenium, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to get the movie names from https://www.sunnxt.com/movie/inside/ website. When I go to inspect element it shows me elements with movie names, but when I perform css selector or xpath expression, it did not give the movie name.

When I click on view source, I saw the code is different there. and all the movie data is placed between

```
<script></script>
```

tag.

Please help me to get all movie name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve the movie names you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) inconjunction with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) as [visibility_of_all_elements_located](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_all_elements_located) as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.sunnxt.com/movie/inside/")
movieList = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[@class='title']//following::div[@class='home_movie_list_wrap']//a//h2")))
for item in movieList:
    print(item.text)
driver.quit()
```

Console Output :

```
Gulaebaghavali
KALAKALAPPU 2
Motta Shiva Ketta Shiva
Annadurai
Aramm
Kaththi Sandai
Meesaya Murukku
Spyder
Sathriyan
Bogan
Brindavanam
Vivegam
Bairavaa
Karuppan
Muthina Kathirika
Dharmadurai
Thozha
Pichaikkaran
Devi
Aranmanai 2
Jackson Durai
Hello Naan Pei Pesuren
Kathakali
Kodi
```

Comment: thats awesome. Thanks alot, but did not understand your code

Comment: In our code we took help of a `xpath` which identifies all the movie names and passed it within `expected_conditions` to wait for their **visibility** which on the elements being visible returned us a _List_. Finally we iterated over the _List_ of _WebElements_ then extracted the text and printed out the _Movie Names_.

Comment: Please let me know where can I learn selenium.. I understand the xpath part but I don't get Selenium

Comment: @Pradeep The best possible way to learn Selenium is to follow a tutorial series of any author and at the same time help others through your innovative code.